# How to check a checkbox in Chrome using Selenium with python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to check a checkbox via selenium in Chrome using python3. 
This is the HTML code:

```
 <header class="list-header">
    <aside class="list-header-bulk-selection">
       <input type="checkbox" class="sc-cSHVUG iAwiCZ">
           ::after
```

I'm trying to check the box by:

```
check_mark = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='sc-cSHVUG iAwiCZ']")
check_mark.click()
```

I am able to find the location, but unfortunately I get the following error message:

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.142)
```

I think I have to access the `::after` line, but I have no clue how I should do this.

Comment: you can try with `find_element_by_css_selector("input.sc-cSHVUG.iAwiCZ::after")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following options to click on checkbox.

**Option1**:

> location_once_scrolled_into_view

```
check_mark = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='sc-cSHVUG iAwiCZ']")
check_mark.location_once_scrolled_into_view
check_mark.click()
```

**Option2**:

> WebDriverWait and element_to_be_clickable

```
check_mark =WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@class='sc-cSHVUG iAwiCZ']")))
check_mark.click()
```

**Option3**:

> Java Scripts Executor

```
check_mark =WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@class='sc-cSHVUG iAwiCZ']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", check_mark)
```

You need to import followings to execute above code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

This `sc-cSHVUG iAwiCZ` looks suspicious and most probably it's automatically generated each time you refresh the page. I would recommend to stick to something more "static", for example the [checkbox](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_checkbox.asp) should have some [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) or other text explaining what it does and you could stick to that text.

From what you've provided so far it might be better to locate this [`<aside>` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_aside.asp) first and then use [child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/child) axis to reach the checkbox like:

```
//aside[contains(@class, 'bulk-selection')]/child::input
```

More information:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a dynamic element so to `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "header.list-header>aside.list-header-bulk-selection>input[type='checkbox']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//header[@class='list-header']/aside[@class='list-header-bulk-selection']/input[@type='checkbox' and @class]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys so much. The thing was that `::after` is a pseudo-element which is not interactable by selenium.

I actually solved it by accessing the checkbox and then hoovering over it (just a tiny bit) to sort of activate the HTML object. Then the checkbox was interactable.

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

check_mark = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='sc-cSHVUG iAwiCZ']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element_with_offset(check_mark,0.001,0.001).click().perform()
```